# Model not found error when install Vue editor js in Vue Js 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3

working with Laravel 8 and Vue Js 3 and installed following Vue Editor js package https://github.com/ChangJoo-Park/vue-editor-js and import detalis in app.js file as following app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import router from './router'
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import mainapp from './components/mainapp.vue';
import common from './common'
import store from './store'
import Editor from 'vue-editor-js/src/index' 

createApp({
    components: {
        mainapp,

        },
    
}).use(router).use(store).use(ViewUIPlus).use(Editor).mixin(common).mount('#app');
```

but when saved app.js file encountered following error message in the console

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js 18:0-35
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-editor-js' in 'F:21 Technics\vue + laravel\vue 3\fullstack\resources\js'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

and I have following warning message in the import file `Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-editor-js/src/index'. 'F:/2021 Technics/vue + laravel/vue 3/fullstack/node_modules/vue-editor-js/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`
`Try`npm i --save-dev @types/vue-editor-js`if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing`declare module 'vue-editor-js/src/index';`

Comment: did you actually install the package? `npm install`  or `npm install --save vue-editor-js
` itself? or you can check if the package exists or not in node_modules.

Comment: i did `npm install --save vue-editor-js` and package available in the node_module